# How to handle routes that have an optional 's' character at the end

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In my backend REST API I have routes for handling products

```
[GET] /products
[GET] /product/:id
[POST] /product/:id
```

I want to handle them all in 1 router (because all these paths do work on products), but the problem is that I don't know how distinguish between `/products` and `/product`. I've tried to use regular expressions like `/product+[s]?` but then `/products/:id` becomes a valid path too which should be invalid.

How to handle both `/products` and `/product/:id` in the same router?

Comment: The route to a specific product should be `/products/:id`, not `/product/:id`.

Comment: If /products and /product have different business logic to be executed,  handle it in '/' path. Lets say in app.js handle like app.use('/', products);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper REST API Structure for specific product is `plural/{id}` so in your case it ideally should be `/products/:id`.

But having said that you can use Regex to match the optional `s`.

```
app.all('/products?/:id?', function (req, res) {
 //will match /product/id also /products/id also /product also /products
})
```

Check out the [`official doc`](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using express framework then you can use `app.all()` route for all request methods i.e `GET,POST,DELETE` and get or show data on condition based by request method.

For further reference https://expressjs.com/tr/guide/routing.html

**example:**

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const url = require('url');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello Express app!')
});

//app.all() will accept GET, POST, PUT, DELETE request method

app.all('/products', function(req, res) {

  var id = req.query.id;

  if (req.method == 'POST') {

    console.log(req.body);

    res.send('return post data');

  }
  else {

    if (id == undefined || id == null) {

      //route : GET /products

      res.send('return all products list');

    } else {

      //route : GET /products?id=1

      res.send('return individual product detail');

    }

  }

})


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

**Test:**

```
 1. To list all products 

    Method GET /products

 2. To get individual product detail

     Method GET /products?id=2

 3. To add new product into list

     Method POST /products
     Request Body (application/json)
     {
        "name":"xyz",
        "description":"Lorem ipsum is placeholder"
    }
```